# How can I import a paralel package in python 3.6.9

Tags: python, python-unittest

I'm creating a project with the following folder structure.

A project with the 'src' package inside it. The 'models' package and the 'tests' package are inside 'src' and each has its own modules inside.

**The problem**: I'm trying import the package 'models' in a module inside the 'tests' package.

This is the folder structure:

```
-project
    -src
       -models
           -__init__.py
           -ArmModel.py
       -tests
           -test_arm_model.py
```

The ArmModel.py defines a class:

```
class ArmModel:
    def __init__(self, definition='std def'):
        self.definition = definition
```

And the test_arm_model.py (where I have the problem) needs to import ArmModel from models to test it:

```
import unittest
from src import models


class TestArmModel(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_arm_model(self):
        arm = models.ArmModel('arm')
        self.assertEqual(arm.definition, 'arm')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I'm having trouble importing "Arm.py" from "models" inside the "tests" module.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "./src/tests/test_arm_model.py", line 2, in 
>       from src import models
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'

Attempt 1:
I tried to use the following code and got the same error

```
from src import models
```

I tried to get the class directly as following and got the same error

```
from src.models.ArmModel import ArmModel
```

And I tried to manipulate the sys.path,

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/jamal/dev/tcc/src/')
from src.models.ArmModel import ArmModel
```

And got the same error

```
from src.models.ArmModel import ArmModel
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

When I tried

```
sys.path.append('/home/jamal/dev/tcc/src/models/')
```

or

```
sys.path.append('/home/jamal/dev/tcc/src/models/ArmModel')
```

the autocomplete from PyCharm IDE couldn't find the package and I got the same error runnig the code.

I also tried to append '../' to the sys.path.
When I tried the code below, I got the ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../')
from src.models.ArmModel import ArmModel
```

When I tried to change the import to

```
from models.ArmModel import ArmModel
```

The IDE displayed an error with >Unresolved reference under models and ArmModel

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.6.9

Comment: @Chris I did what was said and I the same error: >ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'. Looks like my python can't understand 2 folders depth. Maybe I should limit its structure to
src/models.py with all classes inside the models.py
src/tests.py with all tests inside it
Working with a python package inside another is being a pain.

Comment: "I did what was said"—what, _exactly_, did you try? It's always better to show us than to tell us. Please read [ask].

Comment: @Chris I updated my question with everything I did to solve it. 
I could solve it using the base path to my project as following: 
```
sys.path.append('home/jamal/Documents/dev/tcc')
from src.models.Arm import Arm
```

I still don't know why the full path to the module wasn't working. At least it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, I append the path to the project root file "TCC"

```
sys.path.append('home/jamal/Documents/dev/tcc') 
from src.models.Arm import Arm
```

Now I can access all the modules using "src."